# How to write some string value in INI file as per the update in database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, str-replace

For a brief, I have a **USER** which has multiple INI Files uploaded to his account.
The `Path` and `Filename` are stored in the database.

So The INI file has **SECTIONS** then the parameter and the value.

This is my INI File sample:

```
[INIDetails]
SipUserName=
Password=
Domain=182.010.50.59
Proxy=5080
Port=
SipAuthName=
DisplayName=
ServerMode=Automatic
UCServer=192.168.50.5250
UCUserName=
UCPassword=

[DialPlan]
DP_Exception=
DP_Rule1=
DP_Rule2=

[Advanced]
OperationMode=1
MutePkey=16
Codec=
PTime=20
AudioMode=3
SoftwareAEC=
EchoTailLength=5
PlaybackBuffer=10
CaptureBuffer=10
JBPrefetchDelay=60
JBMaxDelay=160
SipToS=
RTPToS=00
LogLevel=
```

So now for values like Domain and Proxy, I store them in the database, and I let the user edit those values.

**Now the problem:**

If there is an update in database value, I loop through and I fetch all the files that user has and I want to update them. So I do this:

```
function update_ini($site_session)
{
    $base_configs= $this->upload_ini_m->get_files();
    //Now Here We Have Files That Has to be updated as per DATABASE PARAMS
    $count = count($base_configs);
    //WE KNOW THE NUMBER OF FILES TO UPDATED

    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) 
    { 
      $filename = $base_configs[$i]->base_ini_filename;
      $path = $base_configs[$i]->file_path;

      //Here We Get Final File To Process//
      $file_to_update =$path.$filename;

     // $file_contents = file_get_contents( $file_to_update);        

      //Parse the INI     
      $file_contents = $this->data['parameters']  = parse_ini_file($file_to_update,true);


      //This is Our Array which has the values so replace the values here.

        foreach ($file_contents as $key => $sections) 
        {
          foreach ($sections as $parameter => $value) 
          {
            //Update files here

          }


        }

    }
}
```

Now I want to put the values that user inserted into database written against the parameter it has, If I update the Domain name then I just want to write the value I get from `POST`and write it against the parameter.

How Can I Achieve This?

I Guess I can use **STR_REPLACE** but how I am not sure. I want to replace the values I get from post from the values in the File.

When I **var_dump()** `$file_contents` I Get this:

```
 array (size=3)
  'INIDetails' => 
    array (size=11)
      'SipUserName' => string '' (length=0)
      'Password' => string '' (length=0)
      'Domain' => string '182.010.50.59' (length=13)
      'Proxy' => string '5080' (length=4)
      'Port' => string '' (length=0)
      'SipAuthName' => string '' (length=0)
      'DisplayName' => string '' (length=0)
      'ServerMode' => string 'Automatic' (length=9)
      'UCServer' => string '192.168.50.5250' (length=15)
      'UCUserName' => string '' (length=0)
      'UCPassword' => string '' (length=0)
  'DialPlan' => 
    array (size=3)
      'DP_Exception' => string '' (length=0)
      'DP_Rule1' => string '' (length=0)
      'DP_Rule2' => string '' (length=0)
  'Advanced' => 
    array (size=14)
      'OperationMode' => string '1' (length=1)
      'MutePkey' => string '16' (length=2)
      'Codec' => string '' (length=0)
      'PTime' => string '20' (length=2)
      'AudioMode' => string '3' (length=1)
      'SoftwareAEC' => string '' (length=0)
      'EchoTailLength' => string '5' (length=1)
      'PlaybackBuffer' => string '10' (length=2)
      'CaptureBuffer' => string '10' (length=2)
      'JBPrefetchDelay' => string '60' (length=2)
      'JBMaxDelay' => string '160' (length=3)
      'SipToS' => string '' (length=0)
      'RTPToS' => string '00' (length=2)
      'LogLevel' => string '' (length=0
```